# ASP.NET C# y SQL Server autenticación tipos de usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Soy una persona totalmente nueva en seguridad y necesito ayuda para la autenticación de tipos de usuario. Todo está ya creado pero necesito ayuda para que dependiendo del tipo de usuario salgan diferentes opciones, estos se validan por medio de una base de datos. Tengo problemas con esto ya que el proyecto está dividido en:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que me está generando problemas ya que al ingresar el login, sin importar el tipo de usuario se dirige a una página Home.master. La cual es de donde se llaman todas las ventanas. Esta presenta un .cs y un .designer.cs, además para mostrar la ventana presenta el siguiente código, siendo esta la razón por la que la validación de roles de usuario se me complicó:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.master.cs" Inherits="Banco.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Sistema Muebleria TEC</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            min-height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        iframe {
            display: block;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .frame {
            height: 49px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

            .frame a {
                color: #666;
            }

                .frame a:hover {
                    color: #222;
                }

            .frame .buttons a {
                height: 49px;
                line-height: 49px;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                width: 50px;
                border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
            }

            .frame .brand {
                color: #444;
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 49px;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }

                .frame .brand small {
                    font-size: 14px;
                }

        a, a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container-fluid {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .text-muted {
            color: #999;
        }

        .ad {
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: #222;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            width: 100%;
            color: #fff;
            display: none;
        }

        .scrolling-table-container {
            height: 378px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #close-ad {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #close {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #no-cursor {
            cursor: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="skin-blue">
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Sistema Muebleria TEC</a>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
            <section class="sidebar">
                <div class="user-panel">
                    <div class="pull-left image">
                        <img src="img/avatar5.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left info">
                        <p>
                            Bienvenido sr(a)
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                            <span>Panel General</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmRegistrarClientes.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro Cliente</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmtipoEmpleado.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro Tipo Empleado</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmtipoDocumento.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro tipo Documento</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmtipoTelefono.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro tipo Teléfono</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmEmpleado.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro Empleados</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmContrato.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Registro de Contratos</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmFactura.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Factura</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmMaterial.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Material</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmProducto.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Producto</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmtipoPago.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Tipo Pago</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmDetallePedido.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Detalle Pedidos</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmEnvio.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Envios</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmEvaluacion.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Evaluaciones</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmProveedor.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Proveedores</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="frmPedido.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Pedido</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </aside>
        <aside class="right-side">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOpcionMenu" runat="server" Text="Panel General"></asp:Label>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentBody" runat="server">
                        <!-- CARGAR EL DISEÑO DE LA PAGINA QUE HEREDA DE MASTER PAGE-->
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </aside>
    </div>  <!--fin del Wrapper-->
    
</body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

No comprendo como podría separarlo de una forma en la que no haya que votar totalmente el proyecto. Un ejemplo de lo que necesito es que si el usuario es un cliente solo deba aparecer: Factura, Pedido, Material, Productos, Detalle pero al ser un empleado deba aparecer: Registro Cliente, Registro Empleado, ect...

Comment: Ya tienes asignados roles de usuario ?

Comment: @soyunewok solo en la base de datos, lo que no comprendo es como realizarlo en asp.net

Comment: Como lo mencionó @soyunewok es importante tener roles de usuario. Lo que tu necesitas es realizar validaciones por rol. 

**Ejemplo**
``if (usuario.isAdmin()){
      habilitarPanelesAdmin.setTrue(true);
}``

Comment: @FernandoCarraro y esto asumo que se realiza en Home.master o estoy equivocada?

Comment: @Programadora Ignoro si se deba realizar en ``Home.master``, ya que no has colocado tu código o lo que has hecho. Es importante conocer que has hecho para resolver el problema. Postea tu código y así tendrás mayor posibilidad de que alguien te ayude.

Comment: Cuando estás creando una aplicación ASP.NET te da la opción si quieres incluir autenticación o no. Si la creaste con auntenticación incluida tendrás una base de datos por defecto donde tendrás tus usuarios y posteriormente crear los roles, de esta manera es mas sencillo, ya que solo queda crear los roles.Ahora si lo que quieres es utilizar tu propia base de datos tienes que crear controladores que hereden de la clase IndentityRole y hacer todo lo que te crea ASP.NET para el manejo de roles cuando elijes con autenticación,si quieres usar tu BD, tengo un ejemplo que si gustas te puedo compartir.

Comment: @soyunewok si me puedes mostrar tu ejemplo sería de gran ayuda

Comment: Aqui esta, cualquier duda sigo por aqui https://mega.nz/folder/PEJiVIJa#9Gi9rD_oH8ixoWSbe1ELnA